# TypeError: must be str, not NoneType. But changing my variable to a string didn't work

Tags: python, typeerror

i was working on a programm, that changes your MAC adress in python. I'm really struggling with this error. This is my code so far:

```
import subprocess
import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option("-i", "--interface", dest="interface", help="Interface to change its MAC adress")
parser.add_option("-m", "--mac", dest="new_mac", help="New MAC adress")

(options, arguments) = parser.parse_args()

interface = options.interface
new_mac = options.new_mac

print("[+] Changing MAC adress for " + interface + " to " + new_mac)

subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "down"])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "hw", "ether", new_mac])
subprocess.call(["ifconfig", interface, "up"])
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType
```

This error refers to my print line. I have already tried: 
 `print("[+] Changing MAC address for " + str(interface) + " to " + str(new_mac))`
 
but that didn't work. 
When I do that, I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.Pathlike object, Not NoneType
```

Changing `optparse` to `argparse` in the entire code, didn't solve the problem.
I didn't give any command line arguments, because I want the user to be able to give them themselves.

Hope you can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: please post the complete code and the error in the question itself

Comment: Please include your code and errors in the question, NOT as IMAGES, not as LINKS.

Comment: Paste your code. Highlight it. Hit Ctrl+K.

Comment: Your program requires command line arguments (the interface and the mac address). You didn't pass any.

Comment: Also, optparse is outdated. You should be using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse).

Comment: I really wanted to post the complete code, but for some reason I can't copy and paste my code from the virtual machine, that I'm using to run linux. I'm sorry.

Comment: I just changed my entire code, using argparse, but I am getting the same TypeError like when I'm using optparse

Comment: I don't see how the error you show is from the line you claim, unless you have redefined `str` somewhere else in the code. Note: your pasted code is not the same as the line you claim is erroring as you aren't calling `str()` in the pasted code. Also please post the full exception.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/root/PycharmProjects/mac_changer2/mac_changer2.py", line 15 in <module>
     print("[+] Changing MAC adress for " + interface + " to " + new mac)
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Comment: maybe it things "interface" and "new mac" are NoneTypes, because the user couldn't pass a command line yet. But my code should tell the program, that the user has yet to pass any command lines

Answer (score 0):

Turnes out my code was perfectly fine. I just had to pass some command lines in the terminal first before running the code. Instead I wanted to run the code and then pass arguments.